# Firebase can't find item pyrebase4

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

After initialising firebase, I've been trying to run the following code

```
self.db.child("devices").update({"passwords": [], "can_open": "false", "state": self.state.value})
```

However, I keep getting the same error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://<project id>.firebaseapp.com/devices.json]
```

I'm currently using the pyrebase4 library. What can I do to resolve this?

edit:
heres the pyrebase initialization code:

```
        firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        self.db = firebase.database()
        self.db.child("devices").child(uuid).stream(self.sync_data)
```

```
config = {
    "apiKey": "api key",
    "authDomain": "<project id>.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://<project id>.firebaseapp.com",
    "storageBucket": "<project id>.appspot.com",
}
```

Comment: This URL in the error message looks unusual: `https://<project id>.firebaseapp.com`. Can you show how you initialized Pyrebase?

Comment: Alright, I've added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have entered the database URL wrong:

If your database is in the US, its URL is of the format: `https://<project id>.firebaseio.com`.

If your database is in one of the other regions, its URL is in the format: `https://<project-id>-default-rtdb.<region>.firebasedatabase.app/`.

Comment: I think the url is actually for the realtime database and not firestore! I read somewhere the firestore no longer requires the databaseURL but if I remove it from config then the pyrebase initialization doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is using the Realtime Database (`firebase.database()`) so that URL is needed, and needs to match the pattern I outlined in my answer.

Comment: ah I understand now! So the database is for the realtime database not firestore. Looking at the documentation, I'm a little unsure if firebase.storage is for firestore? Although the functionality for firebase.storage seems to be quite limited. I guess I'm gonna have to use firestore then! Thank you.

Comment: Firebase Storage (nowadays called Cloud Storage for Firebase) is a product for storing raw files, without any querying capability. Firestore and Realtime Database are both NoSQL databases. To pick between the latter two, this would be a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore